# How can I force Flex to load a particular element first?

Tags: apache-flex

I have a read-only accessor whose value depends on the width of an image. The width of this image determines all sorts of positional values defined in flex. It turns out that, when I load, the accessor returns 0 for a while, and then, about when the thing starts to accept input, it returns its proper value.

Is there any way that I can force Flex to load the image first, thereby specifying its width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't u load the image using Loader class, and loader class has load complete event, and then on load complete of image, do whtever u want,

```
var loader:Loader = nee Loader();

loader.load(new URLRequest('tree.png');
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,productLoadingComplete);   
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,productLoadingError);


private function productLoadingComplete(event:Event):void
{

}
```

Comment: I considered something like this, but it spoiled the simplicity of doing these things in flex.

Comment: bt dear, it 's the only soln sometimes, coz, even i in some projects, got stuck on image loading, if the image loading is not done, i can't pursue further, if u have got some good soln , then plzz let me know as well, hav a gr8 time, bbbye